# count occurrence of a character in a given string

Tags: java, string, count, character

I froze onto the following code for counting occurence of a character in a string:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String source = "hello low how ale you";
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String temp = in.nextLine();
    char test = temp.toCharArray()[0];

    int fromIndex = 0;
    int occurences =0;

        while(fromIndex>-1)
        {
        fromIndex = source.indexOf(test, fromIndex);
        System.out.println("found at"+fromIndex);
        //if(fromIndex!=-1) occurences++;
        }
    System.out.println(occurences);
    }
```

The loop runs infinitely if the "if(fromIndex!=-1)" line is commented out!
The loop properly terminates if the same line is uncommented.
Its strange to observe that loop's termination depends on  variable `fromIndex` and not on the updation of variable `occurences` which is being updated inside the If block.

Any guesses as to why this is happening?

Comment: the code could be in a single line: `int count = StringUtils.countMatches(source , "h");`

Comment: If it runs indefinitely, what's the output inside the loop then? It should print `found at<number>` continuously...

Comment: @vulkanino If he uses Apache commons.

Comment: @Andreas_D - thanks for the prompt response. If the loop runs infinitely then it only prints the first index at which this character occurs. If the input is 'l' then "found at 2" is printed infinitely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the fromIndex value is not changing in the subsequent iterations. Thats the reason behind the endless loop.Thats because fromIndex will give the exact index of the character. increment the fromIndex by 1 for the next loop and tht would solve the problem.

```
while(fromIndex>-1)         
            {         
                fromIndex = source.indexOf(test, fromIndex+1);         
                System.out.println("found at"+fromIndex);         
                if(fromIndex!=-1) occurences++;         
                }          
            }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Then there should be no need for an 'if' condition inside the loop. Because the loop is expected to terminate in case of 'fromIndex' being -1 (i.e. char not found from 'fromIndex' till the end)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do something like below.

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String source = "hello low how ale you";
        char test = 'u';
        int fromIndex = 0;
        int occurrences = 0;
        int length = source.length();
        while (fromIndex < length) {
            int index = source.indexOf(test, fromIndex);
            if (index != -1) {
                occurrences++;
                fromIndex = index;
            }
            fromIndex++;
        }
        System.out.println(occurrences);
    }
}
```

Some explanation-

1. Suppose you need to find 'h' in the given string, you will start from 0, so your `fromIndex` initialization will be 0.
2. You search from initial position till the end of the string. That's why in the while loop, you need to give your condition as, `fromIndex < length`.
3. Now, try to find the occurrence of your test. If there is a test character, you get its character. Else you get -1. Store it in `index`.
4. Now if the `index` is not -1, assign it to `fromIndex`. Because you will now search starting from this position. Not again from 0.
5. Increment `fromIndex`. This will be done regardless of the value of `index` variable.

   Now analyze your code for errors.

Comment: yes. but i m still clueless as to what went wrong with the original code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not strict on using an approach like in your code, I suggest you to use a regex. You will have cleaner and less code, too. Try the code snippet below, let's say you have character `ch`:

```
char ch = 'o';
String input = "Hi there boys! Come on!";
String regex = ch + "";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

ArrayList<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
while (m.find())
    matches.add(m.group());

System.out.println(matches.size());
```